# php and js-ajax acting funny (explanation inside)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am having trouble with this ajax. The return is funny. The switch seems to always evaluate as though #about is true. And include the rest of the switch statement in the #page variable. For instance my PHP code prints this (as well as the #about that it is supposed to) the code at the bottom should clarify what I mean.

To recap it echoes everything past the first $page ='

on my page I see this below what it is supposed to echo

```
   ';
           break;

    case '#register' :
           $page = 'k';
           break;

    case '#contact' :
          $page = 'a';
    break;

     case '#a' :
        $page = ' b';
        break;

     case '#b' :
        $page = '<p> c</p>';
        break;


      default;
    echo "def";
   }
   echo $page;
```

Not to mention it wont even work for #contact, or #a, #b...etc. I am not sure why. Regardless of the url passed it appears as though #about is called with what it returns (even though it returns about and more).

I would really appreciate some help! Thank you

Here is my code:

the js =]

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    //highlight the selected link
    $('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');

    //Seearch for link with REL set to ajax
    $('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {

        //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;

        //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

        //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //hide the content
            $('#content').hide();
        console.log(this.href);
        //run the ajax
        getPage();

        //cancel the anchor tag behaviour
        return false;
    }); 
});


function pageload(hash) {
    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
    console.log("k");
}

function getPage() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
    $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
            $('#content').html(html);

            //display the body with fadeIn transition
            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');       
        }       
    });
}
```

the php =]

```
switch($_GET['page']) {
 case '#about' :
        $page = ' HTML stack overflow formats it, anyways';
        break;

 case '#register' :
        $page = 'k';
        break;

 case '#contact' :
        $page = 'a';
        break;

  case '#a' :
     $page = ' b';
     break;

  case '#b' :
     $page = '<p> c</p>';
     break;


   default;
 echo "def";
}
echo $page;
```

thank you again!

Comment: Where is the getPage method?

Comment: can you send the rest of the switch statament

Comment: are you sure your PHP is actually being executed as PHP ? do you have the `<?php` tag at the top of your `loader.php` file? Also URL fragments (eg. #about #register) are not sent to the server, so your PHP would have no knowledge of them.

Comment: Yeah I have the php tags =]

the #about should be passed as a parameter? The JS that passes it is there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also in the php file, try putting this on top of the script:

header("Content-Type: text/html");